# pact- Contract Testing- The PACT file is not getting picked up for the execution

Tags: pact

Initially started to analyze PACT by downloading the project from github location. In the existing project i have included my code for a GET request services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN.

I was able to generate the PACT file but when i try to verify from the producer end i get the below message

```
 D:\microservices-pact-maven-master\microservices-pact-consumer>mvn    au.com.dius:p
act-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building microservices-pact-consumer 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.2.2:verify (default-cli) @ microservic
es-pact-consumer ---
Loading pact files for provider Foo_Provider from D:\microservices-pact-maven-ma
ster\microservices-pact-consumer\target\pacts
Skipping D:\microservices-pact-maven-master\microservices-pact-consumer\target\p
**acts\Country_Consumer-Country_Provider.json as the provider names don't match pr
ovider.name: Foo_Provider vs pactJson.provider.name: Country_Provider
Found 1 pact files**

Verifying a pact between Foo_Consumer and Foo_Provider
  [Using file D:\microservices-pact-maven-master\microservices-pact-consumer\tar
get\pacts\Foo_Consumer-Foo_Provider.json]
  a request for Foos
    returns a response which
      has status code 200 (OK)
      includes headers
```

Could someone help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Sushma

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with the provider name mentioned in the consumer test where the PACT is getting created. I think your code is having the below values in your consumer pact class.

@Pact(provider = "Foo_provider", consumer = "Foo_consumer")

Please change the provider and consumer names as per your requirement. Run the consumer test again and then run the provider test.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The consumer Pact class has the right consumer and provider names.                                                                           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Pact(provider="Country_Provider", consumer="Country_Consumer")
    public PactFragment createFragment(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Also this is my end point                                   services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN.  The reponse for this is         {"RestResponse": {"messages": ["More webservices are available at http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/services.htm","Country found matching code [IN]."],"result": {"name": "India","alpha2_code": "IN","alpha3_code": "IND"}}}.

Comment: The code that i have written is                                                                          return builder.uponReceiving("a request for Country")
                .path("/iso2code/IN")
                .method("GET")
                .willRespondWith()
                .headers(headers)
                .status(200)
                .body("[{" +
                  "\"name\":\"India\"," +
                  "\"alpha2_code\":\"IN\"," +
                  "\"alpha3_code\":\"IND\"" + "}]").
                toFragment();
    }

Comment: I feel that the entire response i have not included. Do we need to do that.? or will this work

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml plugin for provider you have used please ? Names in the plugin should match what we have in the pact file name.

Comment: Is their a way where i can email across the pom.xml

Comment: Please paste only the plugin part alone starting with <plugin>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.8</version>

Comment: Ok share it to sivaganesh.sivakumar@gmail.com I will have a look and let you know

Comment: Thanks. I have sent an email. Please check

Comment: Hi , Could you please resend the mail again. I think it got missed some where

Comment: Hope your issue is resolved now. please let me know @user3436470